# How to replace HTML5 videos with images only on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, slider, html5-video

**Background**

I am working on a HTML5 video comparison slider. By default, 50% of one video is displayed over the top of a second. The user can move the slider in the middle of the two videos left or right to see more or less of the videos. Both are set to auto play and loop continuously.

However, this functionality does not work well on mobile so I have decided that it would be better to display images instead of videos for mobile devices.

**Problem**
I know that I could use a media query or JavaScript to detect small screen sizes and switch the content. However, I need to target the device not screen width. Is there a reliable way to achieve this?

```
<div class="slider-video__container">
                <div class="slider-video__content">
                    <video autoplay loop playsinline muted>
                        <source src="/img/slider-video/Fragment_02_Light.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-video__seperator">
                    <span class="slider-video__handle"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-video__content">
                    <div class="slider-video__content--resize">
                        <video autoplay loop playsinline muted>
                            <source src="/img/slider-video/Fragment_01_Dark.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best method is to use **media queries**.

Yo can check other navigator or enviroment variables to check what is the device but not are 100% reliables.

Exist more methods to detect the device, it uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the **mobile environment**.

Here is an simple example for User-Agent comprobation with JS:

```
    if(! navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) &&
            ! navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) &&
            ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) &&
            ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) &&
            ! navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) &&
            ! navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry/i) )
    {
        // do desktop stuff

    } else if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) 
    {
       // do tablet stuff

    }
```

You can verify this from several languages, but there are many options available already developed.